# Permutation of a Vector used to create a vector subspace (via Linear Span) of various dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, permutations, vectors

Let $v = (a, b, c, d)$ be a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$. The components of $v$ can be arranged in exactly $24$ ways. For Example: $(a, d, b, c), (c, a, d, b), (d, c, b, a)$, and so on and so forth....

The linear Span  of these $24$ vectors creates a vector subspace $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^{4}$. Find a Vector $v$, such that the dimension of $S$ is: a) zero, b) one c) three d) four

I solved a,b and d with ease (zero: $(0, 0, 0, 0)$, one: $(1, 1, 1, 1)$ four: $(1, 0, 0, 0)$, but I struggled to find a (permutated) vector that would create a vector subspace of the third dimension in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$. A few of my various attempts were: $(1, 1, 1, 0)$ (4 dimensions), $(1, 1, 2, 2)$ (also 4 dimensions), and many, many more.
I have been struggling with this for two days now and I would be very grateful for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

How about $(1, -1, 0, 0)$? Every vector obtained from this by permuting the entries lies in the 3-dimensional subspace $Z$ of sum-zero vectors, and in fact the rearrangements of this vector span the subspace (they include $(1, -1, 0, 0)$, $(1, 0, -1, 0)$, and $(1, 0, 0, -1)$ which span $Z$, since if $a+b+c+d=0$ then $(a,b,c,d) = -b(1, -1, 0, 0)-c(1, 0, -1, 0) -d(1, 0, 0, -1)$).